# Does presence of outlier leads to overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, overfitting

Does the presence of outliers leads to overfitting ?

How to conclude whether the dataset has any outliers ?

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is a highly subjective question and depends on what classification/regression model has been used.

If you are using Linear regression, for sure outliers will affect your line of regression. If you are using KNN, again it would. So it is always a good practise to normalize you data proactively. This in most of cases will save you from over-fitting your model due to the presence of outliers.

But there are many other reasons which could lead to over-fitting.

A very naive but effective approach to detecting outliers is box-whisker plot. You can draw scatter plot also.

Hope this will help.

Comment: What does "normalize you data proactively" means and how is it suppose to help with finding outliers?